# How to store yaml body as string to a yaml key in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

I have a config map as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-string-configmap
data:
  config: |
    timeout: 20m
    images:
      generator: "gcr.io/xxx/xxx/generator:v0.0.1"
```

As can be seen here the `config` is a string which technically is also yaml.

Reading it in python as :

```
 with open(f"conf-configmap.yaml",'r') as f:
        config_string=yaml.safe_load(f)
        config_yaml = yaml.safe_load(config_string['data']['config'])
        config_yaml['images']['generator']="gcr.io/xxx/xxx/generator:v0.0.2"
```

I am able to read and modify the inner properties of the yaml.
However, now I would like to overwrite the yaml file with the new yaml.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-string-configmap
data:
  config: |
    timeout: 20m
    images:
      generator: "gcr.io/xxx/xxx/generator:v0.0.1"
```

I tried the following:

```
config_string['data']['config']=yaml.dump(config_yaml)
yaml.dump(config_string,conf-configmap.yaml)
```

However, this creates the yaml as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-string-configmap
data:
  config: 
    timeout: 20m
    images:
      generator: "gcr.io/xxx/xxx/generator:v0.0.1"
```

The inner body of config, which was initially a multiline string has now become a yaml object.

How do I maintain the inner body as a string itself?
I'm using pyyaml

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior. If I run your code as written, the resulting output has a string value for `data.config`. See [here](https://gist.github.com/larsks/7945b7bbe9cd1b5ab7e9775c4f83e535) for my complete test code, input data, and the resulting output.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
You are right, I wasnt doing a dump, Have update the code.  However, as shared in your code, using the yaml.dump also does not give the desired output. It has tabs ('\t') and ('\n'). Therefore not in the structure that is it intended

Comment: The output has *exactly* the intended structure. There are different ways of representing string literals in YAML; the content of [this document](https://gist.github.com/larsks/7945b7bbe9cd1b5ab7e9775c4f83e535#file-conf-configmap-output-yaml) is **identical** to [this document](https://gist.github.com/larsks/7945b7bbe9cd1b5ab7e9775c4f83e535#file-config-configmap-output-desired-yaml).

Comment: Hmm is there a way to beautify it? For readability?

Answer (score 0):

The value for config in your input is a block style literal scalar. PyYAML can dump all string as such scalars, but it is non-trivial to have only one specific scalar emitted that way.

If you can upgrade to ruamel.yaml, which also lets you preserve comments, superfluous quotes (as for the value of generator), and supports YAML 1.2, this can be done this way:

```py
import sys
import io
import ruamel.yaml
from pathlib import Path

file_in = Path('conf-configmap.yaml')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ=['rt', 'string'])
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(file_in)
config_yaml = yaml.load(data['data']['config'])
config_yaml['images']['generator']="gcr.io/xxx/xxx/generator:v0.0.2"
data['data']['config'] = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.LiteralScalarString(yaml.dump_to_string(config_yaml, add_final_eol=True))

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-string-configmap
data:
  config: |
    timeout: 20m
    images:
      generator: "gcr.io/xxx/xxx/generator:v0.0.2"
```

For this to work you need to run:

```
pip install ruamel.yaml.string
```

in your virtual environment